# Dynamically creating og metadata for page - Client Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, client

I'm trying to set the Facebook open-graph meta data for a page before FB scrapes it, on the client side.

Everything that I tried, it seems that FB scrapes the page before any JS takes action. Is this correct? Is there anyway to do that?

This is how it is in the html file:

```
<meta id="ogImage" content='http://www.blueglass.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/stand-out-in-crowd.jpg' property='og:image' />
<meta id="ogDescription" content='testd' property='og:description' />
<meta id="ogTitle" content='testt' property='og:title' />
```

After the page loads, according to the url parameters, I want to change the metadata.

Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081004/update-facebook-open-graph-meta-tag-through-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is primarily a client-side technology (although server-side implementations exist) that is executed by the browser. When Facebook scrapes your page it is only looking at the HTML structure and content; any JS inside your page will not be executed. Put your URL in to the [Facebook Linter debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see exactly what the linter is seeing.

If you want to set the meta data dynamically you'll need to do this via a server-side script such as PHP or ASP.NET, most likely by interrogating the URL querystring parameters and adjusting the META tags appropriately.