# Write code above <header> tag using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm putting a javascript on a website, I also need to add an open graph tag above the  tag of the page. Is there a way to add the code there using document.write or any other javascript method rather than asking the user to add it by himself which is not easy for a person without html knowledge.

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) What have you searched for?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What's the 'open graph' tag? Why do you need to add it?

Comment: i want to add the open graph type tag <og:type..../>

Comment: Well, you can't update open graph properties once the page loads cause facebook requests it on page load. You should refer to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081004/update-facebook-open-graph-meta-tag-through-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This is the example code to add a paragraph before an element with ID `someID`:

```
   var writeinTo = document.getElementsByID('someID');
   var para = document.createElement('p');
   writeinTo.parentNode.insertBefore(para, writeinTo);
```

Comment: well i want to add the code in between the <head></head> tags, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, 

   var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script= document.createElement('script');
   script.type= 'text/javascript';
   script.src= '<somescript>.js';
   head.appendChild(script);

However, I doubt this will help adding og tags

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `insertBefore`. If you're using jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
$('<meta name="foo" content="bar">').insertBefore('head');
```

Updated example because I thought the OP meant the `<header>` element, not `<head>`.

Comment: does insterbefore works on code above </head> tag? http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/ from here i can see that it only works for tags in between <body> not above that