# Dynamic Facebook open graph tags - javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to read the URL and set `og` tags according to the result I get.

I'm trying `document.write` but Facebook doesn't see them

Example:

```
<head>
  <script>
    if(a==b){
      document.write('<meta property="og:title" content="Wow... A equals B, who knew!" />');
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I believe this has been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081004/update-facebook-open-graph-meta-tag-through-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Graph tags should not be used dynamically, Facebook caches those tags. That being said, the Facebook scraper ignores JavaScript, you would have to add them with a server language. For example, with PHP:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
```